# jQuery .show() only works for a split second

Tags: jquery, css, html, hide, show

I have a div

```
    <div id="fade_bg">
        <div id="login_div">
            <form action="../classes/login/Authenticator.php" method="post">
                <p>username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
                <p>password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
                <p><input type="submit" name="login" /></p>
            </form>
            <p><a id="cancel" href="#">cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

That I only want to show when

```
<a id="login" href="">Admin login</a>
```

is clicked. I used

```
        $(function() {

            $('a#login').click(function() {
                $('#fade_bg').show();
                $('#login').hide();
            });

            $('a#cancel').click(function() {
                $('#fade_bg').hide();
                $('#login').show();
            });
        });
```

However, when I click the link, the div I want to appear only appears for a split second, then returns to normal as if I clicked the cancel button. Why is this happening?

Edit: No errors on the JS debugger console.

Comment: When you submit a form I believe it likes to refresh the page.  Try adding `onsubmit="false"`

Comment: You'll need to prevent the default action of the anchor. In some browsers an empty href will reload the page, and a hash href will scroll to the top:

Comment: firstly i think its a good idea to use e.preventDefault within your call, you need to prevent the default behaviour of the anchor as you are introducing some new functionality

Comment: looks like your answer is below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('#login').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fade_bg').show();
    $(this).hide();
});

$('#cancel').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fade_bg').hide();
    $('#login').show();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kj3xX/)

Answer (score 0):

The submit button always post the form so

```
<input type="submit" name="login" />
```

Replace it with

```
<input type="button" name="login" />
```